# AWS Amplify Email SignUp NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Trying to setup auth with Amplify. After sign-up, Amplify sends a verification email but I'm getting a link that just gives me a 404. The user remains unverified on the user pool. Am I missing something obvious?

[amplify auth signup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKEuc.png)

Comment: Getting the same error, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: The problem was that amplify auth creates an s3 bucket with static assets which are used when a user clicks a confirm email link. You have to configure the s3 bucket to serve those static assets

Answer (score 3):

You will need to enable static website hosting from the bucket properties.

Your properties will likely have Static Hosting Disabled.

[Static hosting config enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEKi3.png)

Steps:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
2. In the Buckets list, choose the name of the bucket that you want to enable static website hosting for.
3. Choose Properties.
4. Under Static website hosting, choose Edit.
5. Choose Use this bucket to host a website.
6. Under Static website hosting, choose Enable.
7. In Index document, enter the file name of the index document, typically index.html.

*AWS Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step2-create-bucket-config-as-website*